# How would you explain what this does?

Tags: tkinter

So, I have to do a report about my tkinter app, but i am not finding the words to describe what this part of the code does. How would you explain it?

```
class App(customtkinter.CTk):

    (...)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.start()
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Do you mean the `if __name__ == "__main__":` part? In which case, read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do

Comment: No, mostly i mean the `app = App()` part. I know what it does, but how to explain it?

Answer (score 2):

I'll break it down in to a few parts

```
app = App()
```

Creates an instance of the class `App` with the name `app`.

```
app.start()
```

Calls the `start` method of the App class instance. Presumably this is equivalent to using the `mainloop` method as is normally done with tkinter rather than this `customtkinter` module.